# C++ - What's wrong with this separate compilation code?

Tags: c++, struct, g++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I have this code that I'm trying to debug. It looks okay to me. But I get an error I don't understand.Here's my code

```
//struct.h
    #ifndef STRUCT_H
    #define STRUCT_H
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    struct Person {
     Person();
     Person(int a, string n);
     Person(const Person &p);
     Person &operator=(const Person &p);
     ~Person();
     int age;
     string name;
    };

    #endif

//struct.cc
    #include "struct.h"

    Person::Person(): age(0), name("noname") {
     cout << "Creating default Person" << endl;
    }

    Person::Person(int a, string n): age(a), name(n) {
     cout << "Creating: " << name << "," << age << endl;
    }

    Person::Person(const Person &p) {
     name = p.name;
     age = p.age;
    }

    Person& Person::operator=(const Person &p) {
     Person person;
     person.name = p.name;
     return person;
    }

    Person::~Person() {
     cout << "Destroying: " << name << "," << age << endl;
    }

//structMain.cc
    #include "struct.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
     Person one(21, "Zuhaib");
     cout << "I am " << one.name << ". I am " << one.age << " years old" << endl;

     Person two;
     cout << "I am " << two.name << ". I am " << two.age << " years old" << endl;

     two = one;
     cout << "I am " << two.name << ". I am " << two.age << " years old" << endl;
    }
```

I compile with

```
g++ -c struct.cc 
g++ -c structMain.cc

g++ -o struct.o structMain.o
```

I then get the following error

```
structMain.o: In function `main':
structMain.cc:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `Person::Person(int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
structMain.cc:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `Person::Person()'
structMain.cc:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `Person::operator=(Person const&)'
structMain.cc:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `Person::~Person()'
structMain.cc:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `Person::~Person()'
structMain.cc:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `Person::~Person()'
structMain.cc:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `Person::~Person()'
structMain.cc:(.text+0x1f4): undefined reference to `Person::~Person()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think I included all the right files. I double checked the declarations and definitions. I'm just not sure why these errors are coming up. It looks fine to me.

Also, in the main function, what happens at the line

```
two = one;
```

I wonder this because, I've overloaded the operator=, but I've also defined the copy constructor which also executes when "=" is encountered. So in the above case, does operator= execute or the copy constructor.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please reconsider your use of bad practices [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html).

Comment: last line of separated compilation seams strange. Try without `-c` option

Comment: @Garf365. I'm sorry, that was supposed to be a -o. I've changed it

Comment: Also, check your assign operator : an assign operator should modify current instance, but not yours. You should write something like that `Person& Person::operator=(const Person &p) {
    name = p.name;
     return *this;
    }`

Comment: try `g++ -o out struct.o structMain.o`

Comment: `-o struct.o` will output to `struct.o`, not read it, it that really what you are typing?

Comment: Try : `g++ -o myapp struct.o structMain.o` after recompiling struct.cc and structMain.cc

Comment: @BoBTFish, Thanks for the advice. However, I've gotten very used to using namespace std; It's hard to program without it.

Comment: @Q_A: get rid of that habit ASAP.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question since it's a simple typo resolved in a manner which is unlikely to help others.

Comment: Just to clarify, I get that error after I run g++ -o struct.o structMain.o

Comment: @Q_A What about if you use what the answer suggest?

Comment: @Q_A It might be harder for you to program without it now, but it will be even harder for anyone to read it later.

Comment: My mistake. So, I've done g++ -o myapp struct.o structMain.o I am getting output. however, the output isn't quite correct. I'll edit my post

Comment: @Q_A: Don't. That would be an entirely different question.

Comment: @Q_A: Your edit renders all existing answers invalid. One question per post, please.

Answer (score 4):

When you use:

```
g++ -o struct.o structMain.o
```

`g++` tries to produce an executable by using the code from `structMain.o` and put the resulting executable in `struct.o`. Since `structMain.o` does not have all the object code to create the executable, you get the linker errors.

You need to use:

```
g++ -o MyProgram struct.o structMain.o
```

Here, `g++` tries to produce an executable by using the code from `struct.o` and `structMain.o` and put the resulting the executable in `MyProgram`. Assuming you have all the required object code in those two files, that should work.

Comment: A proper answer explains why, rather than just dumping a line of "code".

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, thanks for prod.

Comment: np and it's better now

Answer (score 2):

```
g++ -o struct.o structMain.o
```

This tells `g++` to take the object code in `structMain.o`, turn it into an executable, and name that executable `struct.o`.

As your compiler does exactly what you tell it to, you have just overwritten the object code in `struct.o`, which happened to hold the definition of your `Person` class, so yes, the references to that class by `structMain.o` remain unresolved.

What you *want* is:

```
g++ struct.o structMain.o
```

...or give an explicit output name *that is not also the name of one of your input files*...

```
g++ -o someGuessedExecutableName struct.o structMain.o
```

A common convention is to name a source file after the class it defines, i.e. name it `Person.cc` and `Person.o` instead of `struct.cc` / `struct.o`... which would have made that error more visible.

Comment: Would be good to show the complete solution (per RSahu's answer) including usage of the `-o` switch.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: I can only guess what name the OP intended for the executable... ;-)

Comment: True, but `myExecutableNameHere` would do :P

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: LOL... I went for `someGuessedExecutableName`, I hope that's OK as well. ;-)